How can I fix my Ubuntu 24.04 with broken package system?
I am contacting you in order to receive help to repair my Ubuntu OS. Two weeks ago I tried to install a protection against viruses and other cyber threats on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, but I did something wrong, which resulted in the APP Center being completely deleted and therefore, the applications for Mozilla Firefox, Chromium, Music Player as well as Clementine, among other applications, being uninstalled.
To try to solve the problem, I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04, thinking that all the packages would be reinstalled and everything would go back to normal. But that was not the case, now everything remains the same and the software updater does not work when installing updates, warning me that: The package system is broken.
I would greatly appreciate your help in this regard.
My laptop is a Lenovo G50-70 and the OS is Ubuntu 24.04.


Open a terminal. Run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade. Copy (not screenshot) the entire output of both commands. Paste both into your Question above.

Remove the conflicting packages first.
Enter the commands
sudo apt remove thunderbird thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us
sudo apt autoremove

Install all available updates
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

If Ubuntu's default packages (e.g. app center/firefox) are still missing, you can install all of them with
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^

You can later install thunderbird with
sudo apt install thunderbird

